# Strange caching/query planning issue

Tags: neo4j, configuration, neo4j-apoc

I am facing problems trying to keep the Neo4j cache warm. To describe the setup:

- neo4j 3.2 EE
- running in docker
- apoc installed
- cache configs still factory default

My application lets the user do certain set interactions with the graph represented by parameterised queries. Now as I am optimising those, I am running across a strange issue: Every few hours or so, the simplest query with 2 db hits takes 300ms the first time I execute, as Neo4j browser tells me - which would seem entirely too long. It is something like `match (n:Mynode {uniqueid: $id}) return n`.

Afterwards it runs in 2ms, until I leave the graph alone for some hours. Now in my humble understanding of how the db works I see 2 possible reasons for this behaviour:

- The node cache doesn't contain the needed information yet - which is strange because I have `apoc.warmup.run(true)` scheduled every 180 seconds. Maybe the apoc warmup isn't enough or working incorrectly?
- The query has to be planned first - which seems strange because 1. I would assume planning the query shouldn't take 300 ms and 2. The query plans are flushed every 10 seconds by default, but after 2 minutes of no db interaction, it still runs fast

Does anyone more experienced with optimising the config know whats wrong here? Thanks a lot.

**edit for clarification:**

- since i am the only developer on the instance, there are no parallel queries. ATM I am only benchmarking this while developing
- i don't know what a GC is, but there should not be load on the server in general nor on the db
- the graph is not large. it contains under 10000 nodes in my toy example. also the queries have under 1000 db hits each
- there are about 20 parameterised queries which are the only interactions made by the app
- even when I delete/reimport the whole graph the queries are running fast afterwards - so I can actually discard considering query plan issues.
- it seems more likely to be some other caching issue (**maybe docker volumes..?**). I will look into the page cache

**edit 2:**

- can be easily replicated locally (same docker images as on the web server). pretty normal win 10 machine and nothing else running

Comment: FYI, `GC` is `Garbage collector`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly it's really strange to execute `apoc.warmup.run` procedure every 180 seconds ... this procedure reads the **entire database** to populate the (page) cache. So the cost of this execution can be really **heavy**.
You should use it only when you start the database.

A query time depends not only on the query itself, but also on the **database load**.

If you have ten simultaneously queries on a server with 2 cores, you will not have the same query time than if you run the queries one by one.

So perhaps :

- you have an heavy execution that takes a lot of CPU or RAM.
- you execute your query during a GC
- you have a lot of parallel queries
- ...

That's why generally people don't look at the worst query time, but prefer to use the 90 percentile.

About the query plan cache, you should read this KB article : https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-the-query-plan-cache/

You will see :

- How to detect that a query plan is flushed (check the `debug.log` for entries like that : `Discarded stale query from the query cache: match (n:Person)`
- Query plans are not flushed after 10 seconds. It's just that a query plan **can** be flushed after 10 seconds (cache flush eligibility). A query plan will be flushed depending of the divergence stats of the database : `cypher.statistics_divergence_threshold` params
- Neo4j keeps only the 1000 last query plans (see `dbms.query_cache_size`)

Moreover, on the *Enterprise Edition*, you can enable the query log feature with the `page hits` and `page fault` to see if you are using the page cache.

Documentation is here : https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.logs.query.enabled

Comment: thank you for all the detail. please see my edit above for clarification!